# Query the event just before the user did event_name = 'app_remove' using BigQuery Firebase data

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

I need help in a SQL query in BigQuery. I want to know what event did the user did before he/she uninstalled the app (event_name = 'app_remove')

I am trying to get 'event_timestamp', 'event_name', 'event_params.key', 'event_value.string_value' just before a user triggers event_name = 'app_remove'.

My data looks like this: (there's a column named 'user_pseudo_id' not visible in pic)

[image]

I used below query to get the 'user_pseudo_id', 'event_params.key', 'event_value.string_value' associated with users who did event_name = 'app_remove'.

```
    SELECT
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp),
user_pseudo_id,
event_name,
e.key,
e.value.string_value
FROM
  `privatedata.events_20201129`, unnest(event_params) as e
WHERE
user_pseudo_id in
(
SELECT
user_pseudo_id
FROM
 `privatedata.events_20201129`
WHERE
event_name = 'app_remove')
```

However, I only want that event (and also it's parameters) which was performed just before the 'app_remove' event.

Any help for me will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Shantanu Jain

Comment: Your sample data has no "app_remove" event.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, actually the data has a billion rows and I tried to get a screenshot of app_remove but manually finding is very difficult since, the event has occurred very less times.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking of using array logic;

```
SELECT p.*, event_params[SAFE_OFFSET(n - 1)]
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             (SELECT MIN(n) 
              FROM unnest(event_params) ep WITH OFFSET n
              WHERE ep.event_name = 'app_remove'
             ) as app_remove_n
      FROM `privatedata.events_20201129` p
     ) p
WHERE app_remove_n IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks for such a quick response. I used the query and got an error - "Unrecognized name: p at [2:14]". I couldn't fix the error. It would be great if you can help.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thank you so much for the edit. Sorry to write again, but now I am getting a different error: "Field name event_name does not exist in STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>> at [5:24]"

Would be highly obliged if you can look into it..